# Allow unique $_GET request only? Generate, verify, forbid values

Tags: php

Hello everyone again here,
I want to create a PHP script for my software which generates and returns the specific code using one $_GET request with a string and using another verificates this code, then forbid running same string.

Something what should work like this:
1st user's software runs "http://example.com/codes.php?create=" and string like "abc".
and script returns code based on "abc", e.g. "4aO45k", "12sdF4" etc.
2nd user's software runs "http://example.com/codes.php?verify=" and this code.
If this code exists, return true and remove it FOREVER, meaning this code will never be generated again. If this code doesn't exist, return false.
If 1st user's software will run "http://example.com/codes.php?create=abc" another code will be generated.

In simple words:

```
if $_GET is create, then
    generate random alphanumeric string, save it and return
if $_GET is verify, then
    check if this string exists, if so, then
        return true, remove from saved
    otherwise
        return false
```

Possible without databases, SQL, mySQL, FireBird...?
How do I make it using .ini files as storage?

Thanks.

Comment: I don’t think the ini file format would give you any benefit here. You don’t have data with a complex structure, you just have a list of values - so you might as well just write it to a file as such - one value per line, or comma separated, … But with a growing number of already used codes, reading / parsing / searching that file will probably become slower … a database might be the better option, if you really need this for a large amount of data.

Comment: The `remove from saved` comment part makes less sense, of course - you need to _keep_ these codes stored, how else will you tell which have been used already? If anything, you need to switch a flag in your storage, that marks a code as either unused yet, or used.

Comment: misorude, well it must contain both string and code in pairs. Like abc=98dseJ1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with files. You can do something like the simple solution below:

**A couple of notes:**

- I don't know what you intend by `based on` exactly, so this just uses the input as a prefix
- This stores every code in a file indefinitely; if used a lot this file will grow very large and checking for the existence of codes, and ensuring new codes are unique can grow very slow
- The same code can be verified multiple times, but will never be recreated. Marking them as used after verification is of course possible as well
- As a general rule don't go creating global functions and shoving everything in one file like this. It's really just proof of concept of what was asked

```
<?php
$file = fopen('codes', 'a');

if (!empty($_GET['create'])) {
    $seed = $_GET['create'];

    do {
        $code = uniqid($seed);
    } while (codeExists($code));

    fwrite($file, $code . "\n");
    echo $code;
}
else if (!empty($_GET['verify'])) {
    echo codeExists($_GET['verify']) ? 'found' : 'not found';
}

function codeExists($verification) {
    $file = fopen('codes', 'r');
    $found = false;
    while ($code = trim(fgets($file))) {
        if ($code == $verification) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks in general!
1. based on means it converts string to chars and uses them as seed
2. can't argue, but codes shall be removed after verification
3. I need vice versa :) Can be recreated unless it already exists, but can be verified only once, deleting it
4. Okay, thx
Have a nice day, **RESOLVED**.